# How to pass a parcelable object that contains a list of objects?

Tags: android, android-activity, android-intent

I have created a `Parcelable` object below, my object contains a `List` of Products. In my constructor how do I handle re-creating my `Parcelable` for the `List`?

I have checked all of the methods available from the parcel and all that is available is `readArrayList(ClassLoader)`.  I'm not sure if this is the best approach, your advice would really be appreciated.

```
public class Outfits implements Parcelable {

    private String url;
    private String name;
    private List<Product> products;

    public String getUrl() {
        return url;
    }
    public void setUrl(String url) {
        this.url = url;
    }
    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }
    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
    public List<Product> getProducts() {
        return products;
    }
    public void setProducts(List<Product> products) {
        this.products = products;
    }

    public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
        Log.v("", "writeToParcel..." + flags);
        dest.writeString(url);
        dest.writeString(name);
        dest.writeList(products);
    }


    public static final Parcelable.Creator CREATOR = new Parcelable.Creator() {
        public Outfits createFromParcel(Parcel in) {
            return new Outfits(in);
        }

        public Outfits[] newArray(int size) {
            return new Outfits[size];
        }
    };

    @Override
    public int describeContents() {
        return 0;
    }

    /*** Here how do I populate my List of Products ***/
    private Outfits(Parcel in) {
        url = in.readString();
        name = in.readString();
        products = in.read ???????;
    }
}
```

Comment: And what's wrong with `readList()`?

Comment: The method readList(List, ClassLoader) in the type Parcel is not applicable for the arguments ()

Comment: Nothing wrong with arguments. That's how lists are often used. I added answer.

Answer (score 109, accepted):

If class `Product` is compatible with parcelable protocol, following should work according to documentation.

```
products = new ArrayList<Product>();
in.readList(products, Product.class.getClassLoader());
```

Comment: Not necessarily. Documentation states that `writeList()` will write objects according to specifications described by `writeValue()` method. http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue%28java.lang.Object%29 Among other things it says that the object can be Serializable. `readList()` is counterpart of `writeList()` and will read the same data.

Comment: @AlexGitelman But using serialization is considered to be bad for preformance, so that's why they made Parcable available, wouldn't doig that makes this pointless?

Comment: I wasn't having luck using this solution as-is. The ClassLoader of null `in.readList(products,null);`, getting exceptions like... Caused by: android.os.BadParcelableException: ClassNotFoundException when unmarshalling: com.example.MyApplication.Product.   The variation to read the list that actually works for me is `in.readList(products,Product.class.getClassLoader());`

Comment: Also don't forget that Product needs to implement Serializable

Answer (score 41):

First, your Product object must implements `Parcelable`.

And then, use `dest.writeTypedList(products)` in `writeToParcel()` method.

Finally, use following code to parse the list:

```
products = new ArrayList<Product>();
in.readTypedList(products, Product.CREATOR);
```

For more infomation, please reference the [Official Document](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html):

Answer (score 6):

In my personal experience, http://www.parcelabler.com/ is an amazing site for this. You just create your class, and copy paste it into the website, and it generates a Parcelable version of your class.

I tested it with a class named "Theme" that contained the following variables:

```
private String name;
private int image;
private List<Card> cards;
```

The writeToParcel function becomes:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeString(name);
    dest.writeInt(image);
    if (cards == null) {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x00));
    } else {
        dest.writeByte((byte) (0x01));
        dest.writeList(cards);
    }
}
```

generated constructor:

```
protected Theme(Parcel in) {
    name = in.readString();
    image = in.readInt();
    if (in.readByte() == 0x01) {
        cards = new ArrayList<Card>();
        in.readList(cards, Card.class.getClassLoader());
    } else {
        cards = null;
    }
}
```

EDIT: make sure that the Card object is also Parcelable!

Answer (score 5):

This should work:

```
in.readTypedList(products, Product.CREATOR);
```

Comment: It is creating problems for me, this works better: 
`products = new ArrayList<Product>();
in.readList(products, Product.class.getClassLoader());`

Answer (score 3):

**Here you go...**

Make sure "Products.java" should be extended with Parcelable

Step 1:

```
 private List<Products> products;
```

Step 2:

```
private Outfits(Parcel in) {
    products = in.createTypedArrayList(Products.CREATOR);
}
```

Step 3:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeTypedList(products);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

implement `Parcelable` on the Product class as well and then

`in.readList(this.list, Product.class.getClassLoader());`

if any of the above solutions didn't work.

Answer (score 1):

The other way is to use  [readValue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#readValue(java.lang.ClassLoader))&[writeValue](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcel.html#writeValue(java.lang.Object)).

```
protected Product (Parcel in) {
        ...
        in.readValue(this.getClass().getClassLoader());
    }

@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel parcel, int i) {
    ...
    parcel.writeValue(**list**);
}
```

Items of the **list** should implement Parcelable

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the `Product` is implementing `Parcelable`, you can use this for writing:

```
dest.writeValue(products);
```

and this for reading:

```
products = (List<Product>) in.readValue(Product.class.getClassLoader());
```

Answer (score 0):

Product must be implements  Parcelable

```
  Product class implements  Parcelable {
          ......
  }
```

Then write you object contains list like

```
public class Outfits implements Parcelable {

     private String url;
     private String name;
     private List<Product> products;

     public Outfits (Parcel pi) {

        bookName = p.readString();
        bookId = p.readInt();
        isColor = p.readInt() == 1;

        //use this well be get err
        //products=p.readArrayList(Thread.currentThread().getContextClassLoader());

        //Pass list use this 
        products= in.createTypedArrayList(Product.CREATOR);

      }

            ...get and set...

     public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {


        dest.writeString(url);
        dest.writeString(name);

        //use this will no working
        //dest.writeList(products);

        //Parcelable list
        out.writeTypedList(products);

     }

 }
```