# Writing/reading an ArrayList of Parcelable objects

Tags: java, android, oop, parcelable

I have a class called `ClassA` which contains a `List` of `ClassB` objects. Both classes implement `Parcelable`.

I am trying to create the read/write methods for this list in `ClassA` and am having trouble. For example I tried:

```
@Override
public void writeToParcel(Parcel dest, int flags) {
    dest.writeList(mClassBList);
}
```

but then

```
private ClassA(Parcel in) { 
    mClassBList = in.readList();
}
```

throws an error because it needs all these extra arguments.

How do I correctly read/write this `List`?

Comment: What is the error it is throwing?

Comment: [This answer might also help](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300608/how-to-pass-a-parcelable-object-that-contains-a-list-of-objects)

Comment: "throws an error because it needs all these extra arguments" -- well, that method returns `void`. You don't assign it to anything. You pass the `List<ClassB>` as a parameter, rather than getting it returned to you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The links suggested by both George and buczek can be really helpful in your case.
Perhaps more directly, you need to do something like this:

```
//Supposing you declared mClassBList as:
List<ClassB> mClassBList = new ArrayList<ClassB>(); 
in.readTypedList(mClassBList, ClassB.CREATOR);
```

I still recommend you check out the answer, especially (as suggested by Buczek) [How to pass a parcelable object that contains a list of objects?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6300608/how-to-pass-a-parcelable-object-that-contains-a-list-of-objects)