# cancel multi asyncTask

Tags: java, android, android-asynctask

this is my code as example

```
MyAsyncTask asyncTask1, asyncTask2, asyncTask3, asyncTask4, asyncTask5;

asyncTask1 = new MyAsyncTask(0);
asyncTask1.execute();
asyncTask2 = new MyAsyncTask(0);
asyncTask2.execute();
asyncTask3 = new MyAsyncTask(0);
asyncTask3.execute();
asyncTask4 = new MyAsyncTask(0); 
asyncTask4.execute();
asyncTask5 = new MyAsyncTask(0); 
asyncTask5.execute();
```

now if i want to cancel any AsyncTask like `asyncTask2` its easy to call
`asyncTask2.cancel(true);`

but i don't know how much times i run this AsyncTask mabye 1000 times so i cant define 1000 `MyAsyncTask asyncTask1000;` for be able to cancel any AsyncTask

this example will explain more

```
private MyAsyncTask asyncTask;
```

and here its maybe called 100 times with loop or any thing else

```
for(int i = 0; i< 30; i++){

asyncTask = new MyAsyncTask(0);
asyncTask.execute();

}
```

now if i  run cancel like this `asyncTask.cancel(true);`
its will cancel only the last asyncTask i refrence it 
and i will not be able to cancel any other `asyncTask` expect last one

Comment: Try making an array

Comment: Try rxJava or create 100 different objects.

Comment: @GursheeshSingh what if activity rotate ?

Answer (score 0):

You could instead have an array of 1000 asyncTasks

for example:

```
MyAsyncTask[] taskArray = new MyAsyncTask[1000]
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    taskArray[i] = new MyAsyncTask(0);
    taskArray[i].execute();
}
```

Then in the scenario where you want to cancel all of them, run through a for loop again with cancel instead.

```
for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
    taskArray[i].cancel();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you are hoping to make a large number of AsyncTasks you want to track you need to store them in an Array you can track, such as:

```
List<AsyncTask> myList = new ArrayList<>();
```

Every time you start an AsyncTask, just add it to the array

```
myList.add(myNewAsyncTask);
```

Now, if you wish to cancel a specific AsyncTask you will need to call:

```
myList.get(asyncTaskPosition).cancel(true);
```

In the above are the primary directives to be able to track and cancel an AsyncTask in a list of AsyncTasks.

About the screen rotation, e.g., the activity that is holding the List is recreated, that meaning you will lose the instance of the Array, there is a well documented way of keeping the instance through fragments that you can read about in the following link:

https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/runtime-changes.html

In a resumed way, you will need a fragment that you will set with `setRetainInstance(true)` which will keep the fragment instance and all it's variables even on rotation change and will allow you to store your array without having the risk to lose it's instance. From there, its pure java logic.

Comment: can i save it with `onSaveInstanceState` ?

Comment: No, you can not save the list in `onSaveInstanceState` but you can save the AsyncTask list in the fragment retained. Take your time to read the documentation in the link I gave you, and come back to me with any question you might have

Comment: please just see this if i can use it to save the arrayList
https://stackoverflow.com/a/41942116/9338812

Comment: These are objects you can manipulate and make Parceable to store over Intent to store `onSaveInstanceState`. The AsyncTask you can't. The documentation is clear and points you in the good practices direction. I advise you to follow them

Comment: hi i do that's .. any problem if i save data to fragment in onSaveInstanceState  ?

Comment: and restore it from fragment in `onRestoreInstanceState`